# For business people to manage, keep binary images in MySQL or just the urls?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, file-upload

I am working on a task to enable image uploading and auto-scaling(from full sized to thumbnail) by jQuery & PHP.

I can naturally come up with two approaches :

First,  store both images as binary objects directly into MySQL;
Second, store only urls to the images and keep the images somewhere on server.

The images are for everyone to view, so there are no security restrictions, as far as I know.

Personally I don't have any preference, however, at the end of the day, it is the business people that are going to manage the images as part of the system(CRUD). So I am wondering 
which seems to be a bit better for them?

Of course I am building a easy-to-use, visualize web interface for the staff to control the process, but I am not sure if that is enough. Lessons told me that if I don't think for the future and seek the most flexible approach, the I will probably screw myself sooner or later.

PS. The following link is what I've found so far, which is pretty cool, no flash involved :)
[Andrew Valum's ajax image upload jQuery plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay but surely, your end users do not have access to the mySQL database, do they?

Comment: @Pekka : no, end users are customers who just view the images as part of their shopping experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, how managers do like the "I know this too, I wanna play with it" thingies.

**Store the images on a server**. This way they can view/put/copy/modify the images the way they are used to: using Windows Explorer. They already know how to do it, and you won't have to write a lot of custom code afterwards to "I want to be able to X images ...".

Answer (score 2):

Like Konerak said, Store the images on a server.
But not in the database but just as a files.
And their names can be stored in the database, if needed.

That's plain, simple and *natural* way

Answer (score 2):

> First, store both images as binary
>   objects directly into MySQL;

Noooo... no.. It's only going to take a month of PHBs uploading 10mp images for you to start crying uncle.

> Second, store only urls to the images
>   and keep the images somewhere on
>   server.

Yes, a thousand times yes. Store the original file in one place and the latest edit in another.

Comment: thanks for the performance comparison, which I didn't think much at all.

Answer (score 1):

IMO both are bad. Images in the DB cause connection pooling troubles, outside causes consistency nightmares.

For a first version I would just stick everything in the DB, this is good enough if you don't have too many users. If it's a success you could consider an integrated solution which handles both types of data, like JCR, for PHP you have [jackalope](https://fosswiki.liip.ch/display/jackalope/Home). A bit complicated though, I wish there were better solutions.

JCR has WebDav bindings, so your managers can navigate the whole contents tree in explorer if they want. Not that I think that is a good idea though. One solution would be to let them play through WebDav, and always roll back the tx at the end :)

Comment: consistency is not that nightmare with files. Just get more experience ;)

Comment: @disown : Thanks for this thorough solution, I will look at it and keep in mind that I can always come back and use this later, after I finish the initial implementation and let them experience the image management process.

Comment: @Col: Well, if you delete your image ref in the db, does the image go away? No. If you delete the image and its ref in a tx and roll the tx back, does your image re-appear? No. I think that you are the one who need more experience.

Comment: to make it sync is not THAT big deal. Just get more experience

Comment: Eh, that is not really easy unless you write a transactional file-system driver. You can do it, but it's bound to cause you trouble. You'll see in the long run.

Comment: Systems like JCR are transactional.